# Evaluate $\int\sqrt{2+x-x^2}\mathrm{dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Is this approach correct? Can the result be simplified?

I got to:

$$\frac{3}{2}\int\sqrt{1-(\frac{2x-1}{3})^2}\mathrm{dx},$$

substituted $\frac{2x-1}{3}=\cos(y)$, and got a result:

$$-\frac{9}{8}\arccos(\frac{2x-1}{3})+\frac{9}{16}\sin(2\arccos(\frac{2x-1}{3}))+C$$

Comment: [Flammable Maths](https://youtu.be/cfE5ZPnp-Qg) derives a more general result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any two antiderivatives should only differ by a constant, by the FTC. The double-angle formulas are sometimes helpful to simplify things once you've found an antiderivative. In particular,
$$
\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)
$$So something like $\sin(2\arccos(\theta))=2\sin(\arccos(\theta))\cos(\arccos(\theta))$. The second term reduces to $\theta$ and the first term simplifes to $\sqrt{1-\theta^2}$ by drawing a triangle.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \int\sqrt{2+x-x^2}dx \\
&\stackrel{\text{integration by parts}}{=} x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \int xd\sqrt{2+x-x^2}  \\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \int x\frac{1-2x}{2\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx \\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \int \frac{x-2x^2}{2\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx \\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{4+2x-2x^2-(4+x)}{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx \\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \int \sqrt{2+x-x^2}dx + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{4+x}{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}} \\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} -I + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{4+x}{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx \Rightarrow
\end{aligned}
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
2I &= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{4+x}{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx = \\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1-2x}{2\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx + \frac{9}{4} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+x-x^2}}dx\\
&= x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \frac{1}{2} \int d\sqrt{2+x-x^2} + \frac{9}{4} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}}dx\\
&=x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2+x-x^2} + \frac{9}{4}\arcsin\left(\frac{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\frac{3}{2}}\right) +C \Rightarrow \\ \\
I &= \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{2+x-x^2} - \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2+x-x^2} + \frac{9}{8}\arcsin\left(\frac{2x-1}{3}\right) +C
\end{aligned}
$$